# Center Column not working in IE 8,9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float

I have a page with three columns. Left and right are floated and the middle is centered with margin auto 0 and overflow hidden to make it fluid. I have been stumbling for hours and can not figure this out :/

I've even tried changing to several doctypes.

I've whittled down the page to this: 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1407764/www/stackoverflow/margin-0/details.html

Any ideas????

[image: Firefox Screenshot]

[image]

******************** Edit ******************* 
This problem only happens when the browser is wider than 1300 pixels or so. 
Update... IE7 works fine, IE8 does not... but if you click compatibility mode, it works!!????

Comment: What is your problem? page looks the same for me in IE8 and firefox.

Comment: Weird... added some screens. FF and IE9 (VMware. The middle column should be centered.

Comment: Please create _minimal_ testcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded your page and wrapped col2 into a `<div>` with no max-width and left/right margins exceeding the widths of the respective floats. It worked in IE8 standards mode.

Comment: Hmmm, was that just an empty div? I tried that with no luck. Also this  problem only happens after 1300px wide.

Comment: Update... IE7 works fine, IE8 does not... but if you click compatibility mode, it works!!????